# How to access widgets which are stored inside a complex GUI structure in Rust GTK?

Tags: rust, gtk

I am developing a GUI application using the Rust GTK4 library. I have several widgets, which are stored inside the complex structure of GTK objects, every one is on different level:

```
Box { Box { Frame { Grid { Entry } } } },
Box { Box { Frame { Box { CheckButton } } } }
```

I have a button on the top level, and I want to collect data from all of these internal widgets upon clicking this button. So, I want to get access to these widgets inside the connect_clicked method of this button:

```
let main_button = gtk::Button::with_label("Collect");
main_button.connect_clicked(move |button| {
    /* Collect data from all widgets. */
});
```

Only one solution I've been able to find is to create a global database record and pass it to widgets using Rc this way:

```
fn generate_first_row(database: &mut Rc<RefCell<Database>>) -> gtk::Box {
    let common_box = gtk::Box::builder() ... .build();

    let llist = ComboBoxText::builder().name("My list").build();

    let database_for_list = database.clone();
    llist.connect_changed(move |llist| {
        database_for_list
        .borrow_mut()
        .set_list_value(&llist.active_text().unwrap().to_string());
    });

    common_box.append(&llist);

    ...
    common_box
}
```

And for the button:

```
let main_button = Button::with_label("Collect");
let database_for_button = database.clone();
main_button.connect_clicked(move |button| {
    database_for_button.borrow().collect();
});
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, because for a text entry, I would have to use the connect_changed method, which will be called every time the user changes input within the entry. If there is a way to access a specific widget directly, I will be able to get active text using .text() method, which I think is more ergonomic.